# Does whereIn in firebase query efficient?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I design a data model like this
[image]

[image]
there a `users` collection that has one field store array of order ids.

When I want information about all orders of that specific user, I use these ids to get data from collection `orders`. by using whereIn

```
List<String> orderIds = (await FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('')
        .doc(QnRWjhJbjViKUEVBvRAr)
        .get()).get('orders');
var result = FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('orders')
        .where(FieldPath.documentId, whereIn: orderIds)
        .get();
```

I just curious. Is `whereIn` effiecient? Does it check every single document in `orders` and test if that id is in `orderIds`? If that true, when there're more data (let say millions) doesn't this will have performance issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore has a very clear performance guarantee: getting results only depends on the data you retrieve and is completely independent of the number of documents that exist in the collection(s) queried. So no, the performance of `whereIn` doesn't depend on the size of the collection.

Comment: so you mean any query is very fast and I don't need to care about?

Comment: The performance of a query is not dependent on the number of documents in a collection.

Comment: how? isn't query need to check every single document if it met condition or not? can you please explain more?

Comment: Firestore only allows queries that it can satisfy by a pretty direct lookup in one of its indexes, and from which it can then return the results from that point on. So it doesn't need to do a so-called table scan, nor even an index scan, it just performs a direct lookup and then returns a slice of the data. A `whereIn` condition may require multiple such lookups (up to 10), but that makes its performance still only dependent on the number of documents you request, not on the collection size.